# Get DNS server IP addresses associated with Azure VMs

Tags: powershell, azure, dns

I have a list of servers which I need to get the DNS server IP settings from, these servers are in Azure. I thought this would be simple to get the nic and query the properties of the nic to isolate the dns ip assigned to it.

I used:

```
$rg = main-rg
Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rg | ForEach { $Interface = $_.Name; $IPs = $_ |`
     Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | Select PrivateIPAddress; Write-Host $Interface $IPs.PrivateIPAddress }
```

To get `privateIPaddress`, but this is for a single resource group. Would I need to put this into a `foreach` loop?

Maybe like:

```
    $rg = get-content c:\temp\list-of-res-grps.txt
foreach ($rgs in $rg)
{
    Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rg | ForEach { $Interface = $_.Name; $IPs = $_ |`
         Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig | Select PrivateIPAddress; Write-Host $Interface $IPs.PrivateIPAddress }  
}
```

To get the name of the nics I used, which also gives hostname.

```
get-azurermvm | out-file c:\temp\servers.txt
```

Is there a way to query the nic for the dns server ip address? Or do I need to be digging deeper into the `Get-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig` cmdlet?

Hope I haven't missed anything obvious.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure, if you have not change DNS, the **default** private DNS is `168.63.129.16`.

**1**.If you change DNS settings via Azure Virtual Network, we can use this command to list the DNS server:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> $a = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name 'jasonvm-vnet' -ResourceGroupName jasonvm
PS C:\Users\jason> $a.DhcpOptions

DnsServers
----------
{8.8.8.8}


PS C:\Users\jason>
```

**2**.If you change the DNS settings with Azure PowerShell, like this:

```
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -Name "NetworkInterface1"
$nic.DnsSettings.DnsServers.Add("9.9.9.9")
```

We can use this command to list the DNS server:

```
PS C:\Users\jason> $d = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name jasonvms790 -ResourceGroupName jasonvm
PS C:\Users\jason> $d.DnsSettings.DnsServers
9.9.9.9
```

**3**.If you change DNS settings in Azure VM, we **can't** use PowerShell to get it. we should login to this VM then to check it.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: thanks for that, I managed to use that in a hash table to extract the dns from both the nic and the vnet, thanks :)